# Discord.py - Running a command once everyday

Tags: python, discord.py

so right now I am trying to make a DailyQuestion command where it basically takes a random question from a text file and sends it into #general. For now the command is just manual and I was wondering if there was a way of using `@tasks.loop` in order to check the time and if it's for say 10:00 AM, post a question. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scheduling library such as https://pypi.org/project/schedule/ to schedule the task for a specific time